# I am trying to run application.But the process stops at uploading stage.Emulator is not responding for long time

Tags: android, emulation

[2012-03-16 10:38:33 - BookshelvesMarch] Android Launch!

[2012-03-16 10:38:33 - BookshelvesMarch] adb is running normally.

[2012-03-16 10:38:33 - BookshelvesMarch] Performing com.diacri.ebooks.BookshelvesMarchActivity activity launch

[2012-03-16 10:38:33 - BookshelvesMarch] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'Android4.0' is available on emulator 'emulator-5554'

[2012-03-16 10:38:33 - BookshelvesMarch] Uploading BookshelvesMarch.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'

Comment: Does this problem occur with other emulator too??

Comment: It is happening in Another Emulator too.I have tried Android 4.0, Android 2.3.1

Comment: then check the .android folder and delete the files of the avd such as userdata, cache , snapshots etc. which will regenerate again from scratch, it worked for me too, basically it increases heap memory of emulator and ultimately the CPU cant manage this memory and will emulator will go in infinite and wont work. try this i hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it problem occurs of lack of memory, try to create the avd with lowest configuration, working with 4.0 needs a bunch of memory and check the .android/avds/avd-name/ directory and check the size of userdata.img,snapshots.img and if they are big in size then just delete it and it will be regenerated but with new size and this will help you to start the 4.0 avd normally, else you should look on your pc's memoery management.

Comment: Thankyou @mak_jus4anything I just deleted some files.It s working now.But Anyways I need to find the way to use file to go ahead with project

Comment: not getting your point "I need to find the way to use file to go ahead with project"

Comment: I had a file (37 MB ) in assets folder of my project.I deleted the particular file.Then the Emulator responded.But I should display the contents of the file in webview.

Comment: then do one thing, go to preferences>android>DDMS and you will see the ADB connection timeout just change it 20000 or more and then try it will solve this, i think

Answer (score 0):

If you are running multiple programs may be Emulator is not getting enough CPU cycles / memory to start properly. I will suggest edit the emulator settings and allocate it more memory (preferably 1024mb) and try again... Normally emulator takes time when it is started for the first time..

An answer [from](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110215093847AAXLkLY) suggests, "if the emulator is still not working, It usually means you are having a problem with ADT. This meaning that if you attempt to debug on device it will error out as well because of a mis-communication with ADT. I suggest un-installing everything and reinstalling it all from scratch making sure that you install the proper drivers that are recommendedas well."

Comment: Thankyou @amit The problem occured due to large file